# how to accumulate several column and do summation?

Tags: r, addition

I want to combine 15 columns which have 3 same columns (so it has 5 same copies of it). My data is looked like this (for the example, it's only 3 copies of it in order to make it simple)

```
   date     sku1  prod1  tot1  sku2  prod2  tot2  sku3  prod3  tot3
01/02/2019  100     a    100
01/02/2019  100     a    200    101    b     50
02/02/2019  101     b    100
02/02/2019  101     b     50    102    c    100   100     a     50
02/02/2019  102     c     50
```

to be like this

```
   date     sku  all_prod  total
01/02/2019  100     a       300
01/02/2019  101     b        50
02/02/2019  101     b       150
02/02/2019  102     c       150
02/02/2019  100     a        50
```

anyone know how to done this? Thanx so much in advance

Comment: please use `dput` to show the example.  Are those blanks (`""`) or `NA`s?

Comment: NOt clear about the conditions.  May be `library(data.table); melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^sku", "^prod", "^tot"), na.rm = TRUE, value.name = c("sku", "all_prod", "total"))[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .(date, all_prod), .SDcols = c("sku", "total")]`

Comment: those blanks are NA

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `melt` from `data.table` that can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^prod", "^tot"), na.rm = TRUE, 
    value.name = c( "all_prod", "total"))[, c(list(sku = first(sku1)), 
    lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE)), .(date, all_prod),
          .SDcols = c("total")][order(date)]
#        date all_prod sku total
#1: 01/02/2019        a 100   300
#2: 01/02/2019        b 100    50
#3: 02/02/2019        b 101   150
#4: 02/02/2019        c 102   150
#5: 02/02/2019        a 101    50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
 c("01/02/2019", "02/02/2019"), class = "factor"), sku1 = c(100, 100, 101, 101, 
 102), prod1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
 "b", "c"), class = "factor"), tot1 = c(100, 200, 100, 50, 50), 
 sku2 = c(NA, 101, NA, 102, NA), prod2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 
 NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("b", "c"), class = "factor"), tot2 = c(NA, 
 50, NA, 100, NA), sku3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, NA), prod3 = 
 structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), tot3 = c(NA, 
 NA, NA, 50, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: i got an error message like this
"In addition: Warning messages:
1: In melt.data.table(setDT(forwhx1), measure = patterns("^skuproduk",  :
  'measure.vars' [skuproduk1, skuproduk2, skuproduk3, skuproduk4, skuproduk5] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. All measure variables not of type 'character' will be coerced too. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion."

Comment: actually the data aren't in sequence like in the example, so i think the "c(list(sku=first(sku1))" make a problem here

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto  With the example you provided, I didn't get any error

Comment: what does "value.name = c( "all_prod", "total"))[, c(list(sku = first(sku1))" mean?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto  By default, if you don't provide that option, the value columnss will be named by its default names, ie. 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', To modify that, we usse `value.name`.  The second part is to get the `first` element of 'sku' based on the grouping variable

Comment: i didn't get what u mean for the second part. Could you explain what is the first element of "sku"?

Comment: i found an error like this "Error in gfirst(sku1) : object 'sku1' not found"
what does it mean?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto  Have you tried the code with the data from my post?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto  Sorry, I can't reproduce the error.  I am using `packageVersion("data.table")#
[1] ‘1.12.2’`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can `gather` the data into long form, remove the numbers from the column names, `spread` it into wide format, `group_by` `date` and `prod` value and take `sum` of `tot` values in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -date, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(key = sub("(.*)\\d+", "\\1", key)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(sku, tot), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(date, prod) %>%
  summarise(sku = sku[1L], 
            tot = sum(tot))

#  date       prod    sku   tot
#  <fct>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 01/02/2019 a       100   300
#2 01/02/2019 b       101    50
#3 02/02/2019 a       100    50
#4 02/02/2019 b       101   150
#5 02/02/2019 c       102   150
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("01/02/2019", "02/02/2019"), class = "factor"), sku1 = c(100, 100, 101, 101, 
102), prod1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), tot1 = c(100, 200, 100, 50, 50), 
sku2 = c(NA, 101, NA, 102, NA), prod2 = structure(c(NA, 1L, 
NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("b", "c"), class = "factor"), tot2 = c(NA, 
50, NA, 100, NA), sku3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, NA), prod3 = 
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), tot3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 50, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what -date ; na.rm means?

Comment: and also what does "mutate(key = sub("(.*)\\d+", "\\1", key))" mean?
thanx

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto Using `gather` we are converting data into key/value pairs where key is the column name and value is the value in the column. By specifying `-date` we keep the `date` column as it is. `na.rm` is used to remove `NA` values. whereas `sub` is used to remove the numeric part from `sku1`, `sku2`, `prod1` and other column names. If the code is too confusing and if you want to better understand the code I would suggest you to run the code line by line and see the output.

Comment: i got an error code like this after run your code -> "Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion "
and the total didn't show the correct addition result

Comment: how if i want to add another column name beside date? so i should write like this "gather(key, value, (-date,-example), na.rm = TRUE)"?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto yes, provided that you have `example` column already present in the data. I am not clear how you get the error though. How is your real data different from the example you shared? Do you have some additional columns?

Comment: yes i have additional 1 column, but it actually only show yes or no in the "example" column. I have try this "gather(key, value, (-date,-example), na.rm = TRUE)" but it show error "Error: unexpected ',' in:
"dummy2=forwhx1 %>%
    gather(key, value, {-date,"" 
How to solve this? Thanx so much @Ronak

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto Strange, if in the data I have shared if I add a new column. `df$example <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes")` and run the above code as it is it works for me without any error. or if you want to exclude `example` do `gather(key, value, -date, -example, na.rm = TRUE) %>%`

Comment: I want to ask what does this code "sku = skuproduk[1L]" mean?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto it selects the first value. For example, do `x <- 1:10` and then `x[1L]` it gives you only first value.